# Restriction to Basis of Cadlag function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, banach-spaces

If $f \in L^2([0,T])$ then it can be written as
$$
f(t) \triangleq \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} c_i e_i(t),
$$
for some sequence $\{c_i\}$ of real numbers and a Schauder basis $\{e_i(t)\}$ of $L^2([0,T])$ of piecewise cadlag function which are smooth on each piece.

My question is there a necessary and sufficient condition on the coefficients $\{c_i\}$ of the basis characterizing any function which is in $L^2([0,T])$ and is cadlag?

Comment: Can't I destroy the "continue a droite" property by changing the values of $f$ on a set of measure zero?

Comment: So?  I m not interested in functions which are not cadlag.  I don't see the problem

Comment: Elements of $L^2$ are only defined up to sets of measure zero - I guess you mean "characterizing those $f$ which are equivalent a.e. to cadlag ones"?

Comment: Yes I agree everything is taken to be a.e. for sure